# Matplotlib issue on OS X ("ImportError: cannot import name _thread")

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-dateutil

At some point in the last few days, Matplotlib stopped working for me on OS X. Here's the error I get when trying to `import matplotlib`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my/path/to/script/my_script.py", line 15, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 34, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 40, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._subplots import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 22, in <module>
    import matplotlib.dates as _  # <-registers a date unit converter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 126, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import (rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 14, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

The only system change I can think of was the Apple-forced NTP update and maybe some permission changes I did in /usr/local to get Brew working again.

I tried reinstalling both Matplotlib and Python-dateutil via Pip, but this did not help.  Also tried a reboot.  I'm running Python 2.7.6, which is located in /usr/bin/python.  I'm running Yosemite (OS X 10.10.1).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

```
sudo pip uninstall python-dateutil
sudo pip install python-dateutil==2.2
```

I had the same error message this afternoon as well, although I did recently upgrade to Yosemite. I'm not totally sure I understand why reverting dateutil to a previous version works for me, but since running the above I'm having no trouble (I generally use pyplot inline in an ipython notebook).

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue for me as well.  I submitted a bug to the developer: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/12

Comment: I think updating your version of `six` would also work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @tcaswell, I looked into it and I am already running the latest version of six.

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/issue/39/sixmoves-missing-thread-_thread, maybe that is a year old though...

Comment: @tcaswell suggestion of updating six worked for me.  I thought I was on the latest version (1.9.0) but it turns out that I had two versions installed, 1.9.0 and 1.4.0 -- finding the old one and deleting it worked great.  Didn't try the dateutil solution.

Comment: Using OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and the OS X system Python (2.7.6) -- I only have one version of `six` (1.9.0) and was still getting this error. The uninstall and reinstall of `python-dateutil` immediately fixed the problem. However, I am still having the (possibly related) problem of not being able to import `pyopencl` because of `from six.moves import intern`. So, all in all, awesome answer, this fixes the exact problem but just sharing that `six` seems still generally broken for OS X 10.10 and Python 2.7.6, FYI. Thanks again for this answer!

Comment: It worked for me in a python 2.7 installation on a Yosemite 10.10.3 machine.
It seems though that quite a few python packages have issues with the "non-standard" locations of the Python libraries in MacOS X.

Comment: Seems to be a new issue in El Capitan -- an old version of "six" is included in ''/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py' which can't be upgraded without disabling rootless.

Comment: Removing the outdated six that comes with OSX python and pip installing a better version is the correct fix IMO, versus recommending downgrading a different package.

Comment: Instead of removing the system version. What I did is setting the system variable: PYTHONPATH='/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'. Or in your application: import sys;sys.path.insert(1,'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages')

Answer (score 45):

This problem is fixed in the latest `six` and `dateutil` versions. However, in OS X, even if you update your `six` to the latest version, you might not actually update it correctly. This is what happened to me:

After doing a `pip2 install six -U`, the new `six` module was installed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`. However, when I loaded `six` in a python 2.7 terminal, and checked its path, this is what I got:

```
import six
print six.__file__
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc
```

So, python was using an old version of `six`, which I removed by typing:

```
rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.*
```

This fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer works with El Capitan because of the protection of the rootless feature.

Comment: I just read what the "rootless feature" is (here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) and it seems like a terrible idea. I guess in El Capitan people will have to use a virtualenv in order to have full control of their Python installs.

Comment: This worked for me on 10.10.4 (I also have a newer version of six which is installed by pip but not imported by default). Thanks.

Comment: Instead of removing the system version. What I did is setting the system variable: PYTHONPATH='/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'. Or in your application: import sys;sys.path.insert(1,'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages')

Comment: For some reason 'sudo pip install six -U' updated the six modules in my /usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages folder. I had to copy six.* from this folder to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages to make it work. Was having error starting docker-compose ...

Answer (score 10):

Installing the `python-dateutil==2.2` did not work for me.

But a quick-and-dirty workaround did work! I replace `six.py` in python 2.7 with the `six.py` from python 3.4 (virtualenv). Since, I have the problem in 2.7 but not 3.4.

**UPDATE**

I had the same problem again after reinstalling python (and after upgrading to El Capitan). Un-obvious thing is that this error occurs only in the `IPython` shell and notebook (when I do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`) but works fine from a Python shell.

So a better solution (that did work in my case) without a dirty work-around is to force install both `six` and `ipython`. Here is what I did to have this fixed :

```
$ pip install --ignore-installed six
$ pip install --ignore-installed ipython
```

Comment: I have the same issue. The dateutil fix did not work. I am not that keen to hack my 2.7, any better ideas?

Answer (score 10):

It is possible that you have a perfectly installed version of any packages you have installed, but the version used by default is not the one you want. You can see the list of paths that python search from in order to find its packages as follows:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

In order to let python search first the most updated version of certain package, instead of removing the system version, what can be done is to set the system variable `PYTHONPATH` in the ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.bashrc if linux) config file to the path where the new packages are installed:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

An alternative is to modify the python path inside your python script by adding the path at the beginning of the path list:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages')
```

This needs to be done for every script you need a certain package version. You might want for some reason use an older version that you have installed.
BTW all my installations with easy_install, or pip, or from sources go to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
This worked en EL Capitan, and now also in macOS Sierra (10.12.2)