# Python cannot import pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to import Pylab in python but i always get the following error,

```
from pylab import *

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 226, in <module>
    import matplotlib.finance
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/finance.py", line 21, in <module>
    from matplotlib.dates import date2num
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/dates.py", line 119, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import (rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 14, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

I am using mac OS. Please any suggestions!

Comment: sudo pip uninstall python-dateutil
sudo pip install python-dateutil==2.2

Comment: gladly i found the issue and now it's working perfect.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630114/matplotlib-issue-on-os-x-importerror-cannot-import-name-thread