# Unable to run odoo properly in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, odoo

I have installed Odoo 9 Community version from Git in my Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2, all my steps:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.10

git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git
Checking out files: 100% (20501/20501), done.
```

Installed [PostgresApp](http://postgresapp.com/) into `Applications` and added path in `~/.bash_profile`, executed the same.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

Installed pip

```
sudo easy_install pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

I have `nodejs` installed in my system,

```
node -v
v5.0.0
npm -v
3.3.9
```

Installed `less` and `less-plugin-clean-css`

```
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

I have latest xcode installed,

```
xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

I have homebrew installed,

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
The current contents of /usr/local are bin Cellar CODEOFCONDUCT.md CONTRIBUTING.md etc include lib Library LICENSE.txt opt README.md sbin share SUPPORTERS.md var .git .gitignore
```

Installed other libs

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool
brew install libxml2 libxslt libevent
```

Installed Python dependencies

```
sudo easy_install -U setuptools
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools

cd odoo/
sudo pip install --user -r requirements.txt

Successfully installed Mako-1.0.1 Pillow-2.7.0 Werkzeug-0.9.6 argparse-1.2.1 lxml-3.4.1 psutil-2.2.0 psycopg2-2.5.4 pyparsing-2.0.1 python-dateutil-1.5 python-ldap-2.4.19 pytz-2013.7 pyusb-1.0.0b2 qrcode-5.1 six-1.4.1
```

Running odoo

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

./odoo.py --addons-path=addons --db-filter=mydb
```

It says

```
2016-02-10 16:51:42,351 3389 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 9.0c
2016-02-10 16:51:42,351 3389 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/Users/anshad/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/9.0', u'/Users/anshad/odoo/addons', '/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/addons']
2016-02-10 16:51:42,352 3389 INFO ? openerp: database: default@default:default
2016-02-10 16:51:42,444 3389 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
```

And the browser says `500 500 Internal Server Error`
and in terminal,

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Started PostgresApp to solve this issue.

Now I got the database setup window appears without CSS as in the below screen-shot.

Created database `mydbodoo` with password `admin` and navigated to main page `http://localhost:8069/web/`
It shows a blank page with black header and odoo logo, some error in terminal as well.

`ImportError: No module named pyPdf`

```
./odoo.py --addons-path=addons --db-filter=mydb
2016-02-10 17:02:12,220 3589 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 9.0c
2016-02-10 17:02:12,220 3589 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/Users/anshad/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/9.0', u'/Users/anshad/odoo/addons', '/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/addons']
2016-02-10 17:02:12,221 3589 INFO ? openerp: database: default@default:default
2016-02-10 17:02:12,314 3589 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2016-02-10 17:02:16,855 3589 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2016-02-10 17:02:16,888 3589 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:16] "GET /web/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2016-02-10 17:02:16,895 3589 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 245, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1487, in __call__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1508, in load_addons
    m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 61, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/addons/document/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import models
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/addons/document/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ir_attachment
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/addons/document/models/ir_attachment.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pyPdf
ImportError: No module named pyPdf
2016-02-10 17:02:17,708 3589 INFO mydbodoo openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2016-02-10 17:02:17,716 3589 INFO mydbodoo openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2016-02-10 17:02:17,719 3589 INFO mydbodoo openerp.modules.loading: loading 4 modules...
2016-02-10 17:02:17,727 3589 INFO mydbodoo openerp.modules.loading: 4 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2016-02-10 17:02:17,899 3589 INFO mydbodoo openerp.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
2016-02-10 17:02:17,900 3589 INFO mydbodoo openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_http: Generating routing map
2016-02-10 17:02:18,249 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "GET /web/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,308 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "GET /web/content/341-42af255/web.assets_common.0.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,350 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "GET /web/static/src/css/full.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,367 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "GET /web/content/343-4d5beef/web.assets_backend.0.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,411 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "GET /web/content/344-4d5beef/web.assets_backend.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,428 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "GET /web/content/342-42af255/web.assets_common.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,663 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "GET /web/binary/company_logo HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,838 3589 INFO mydbodoo openerp.service.common: successful login from 'admin' using database 'mydbodoo'
2016-02-10 17:02:18,859 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "POST /web/session/get_session_info HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,893 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "POST /web/proxy/load HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,915 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "POST /web/session/modules HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,945 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,945 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "POST /web/webclient/translations HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,991 3589 INFO mydbodoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 17:02:18] "GET /web/webclient/locale/en_US HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2016-02-10 17:02:18,998 3589 ERROR mydbodoo werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 245, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1488, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1652, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 186, in _dispatch
    return self._handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 157, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 781, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 182, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 840, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 316, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 959, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 509, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/anshad/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 505, in load_locale
    addons_path = http.addons_manifest['web']['addons_path']
KeyError: 'web'
```

**Screen-shot:Terminal and file system**

[image]

**Screen-shot:Database selection window**

[image]

**Screen-shot: Main window**

[image]

Tried `sudo pip install pyPdf` and it says `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyPdf in /Users/anshad/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`

Comment: @anshad, when you install freshly and open in browser you will get a Database page, there you need to give a DB name, username and password. That will be you default email/username and password.

Comment: I think you have done correctly because you are getting the login screen, go to manage database and create new database, UN and pwd. use that UN and PWD in login page

Comment: Might problem of installing of bootstrap or less. Default login and password will be "admin" and "admin".

Comment: @Odedra How can I fix the library installation issue to get the CSS loaded? I didn't got any errors.

Comment: got a new source of the odoo on github and try

Comment: @JainikPatel I have tried that as well. Still same issue.

Comment: The css/js errors are because your addons path must not be correct. Try launching with `./odoo.py --addons-path=addons --db-filter=mydb$` (remove `openrp/`)

Comment: @l'L'l tried this as well

Comment: In `/web/static/src/img/` do you see for example `logo2.png`?

Comment: @l'L'l I can see all the files like images, css and js in their folder.

Comment: Tried to run like this as well `./odoo.py --addons-path=openerp/addons,addons`. In addons folder I can see web module and all the resource files in that.

Comment: have you tried with another database ? and server start with this *./openerp-server* and checkout what the result came

Comment: @Odedra Yes tried that as well.got screen same as above and the same error.

Comment: @devo If you got *web* error than that's means Server can not find web module as provided *--addons-path* I would suggest that make a empty folder name with web-addons and place all web module relevance. And than give permission for read,write. Now add that *web-addons* path in   *--addons-path*

Comment: I was getting the exact same screen as you above, I did pip install werkzeug==0.9.4

Comment: @devo u may also try to update the werkzeug package form the terminal or Have  you tried to refer the http://www.serpentcs.com/serpentcs-openerp-installation-guide-on-mac-osx-10-9 document it may helpful for you

Comment: In your addons folder, check whether you have base and web modules,there are two addons folder copy all the contents of odoo/openerp/addons to odoo/addons folder then restart the server and try again

Comment: @Bhanukiran I have these files in system. Tried fresh installed as updated in question. But no luck, getting some import error.

Comment: @DaSaDiYaChaiTAnYa That doesn't worked for me. Updated my question with complete steps.

Comment: @Odedra Updated question with full steps, I have the import error in terminal console.

Comment: Can u attach a screenshot of your configuration file?

Answer (score 18):

I just went through the setup on two systems, one is Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 and another one is my primary OS - Ubuntu 15.04 (where things went much easier, but maybe it is just because I use Ubuntu on daily basis).

Below are installation steps for both systems. Make sure that every command finishes successfully (at least doesn't report any errors).

### Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2

Prerequisites: I already had `git` and `python 2.7.10`.

1) Clone odoo repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git
```

2) Download and install `Postgresapp`

- Go to http://postgresapp.com/, download
- Open it in Finder, drag to Applications, double click
- Postgres application appears, double click it
- Sorry if these steps are obvious, it is just for me since I am not a Mac OS user

Now add to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

And just execute the command above it if you already have the open terminal.

3) Install `pip`

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

4) Install `nodejs`

- Go to https://nodejs.org,
- Download node v4.3.0
- Move to Applications, run and install
- Open terminal and check that `node` and `npm` commands are available

5) Install `less` and `less-plugin-clean-css`

```
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

Should show output like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/lessc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
less-plugin-clean-css@1.5.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less-plugin-clean-css
└── clean-css@3.4.9 (source-map@0.4.4, commander@2.8.1)
less@2.6.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less
├── mime@1.3.4
├── graceful-fs@3.0.8
├── image-size@0.3.5
├── errno@0.1.4 (prr@0.0.0)
├── promise@6.1.0 (asap@1.0.0)
├── source-map@0.4.4 (amdefine@1.0.0)
├── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
└── request@2.69.0 (aws-sign2@0.6.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, tunnel-agent@0.4.2, oauth-sign@0.8.1, is-typedarray@1.0.0, caseless@0.11.0, stringstream@0.0.5, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, tough-cookie@2.2.1, node-uuid@1.4.7, qs@6.0.2, combined-stream@1.0.5, mime-types@2.1.9, form-data@1.0.0-rc3, aws4@1.2.1, hawk@3.1.3, bl@1.0.2, har-validator@2.0.6, http-signature@1.1.1)
```

6) Install binary dependencies

I think not all the steps below are really necessary, but I performed them, so include just for the case they actually were needed.

- Run in the terminal `xcode-select --install`, when dialog appears - agree to install
- Go to http://brew.sh and follow instructions to install homebrew

Once you have `brew`, run the following in the terminal:

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool
brew install libxml2 libxslt libevent
```

7) Install python dependencies

```
sudo easy_install -U setuptools
pip install --user -r requirements.txt
```

It should show something like this at the end:

```
Successfully installed Babel-1.3 Jinja2-2.7.3 Mako-1.0.1 MarkupSafe-0.23 Pillow-2.7.0 PyYAML-3.11 Python-Chart-1.39 Werkzeug-0.9.6 argparse-1.2.1 beautifulsoup4-4.4.1 decorator-3.4.0 docutils-0.12 feedparser-5.1.3 gdata-2.0.18 gevent-1.0.2 greenlet-0.4.7 jcconv-0.2.3 lxml-3.4.1 mock-1.0.1 ofxparse-0.14 passlib-1.6.2 psutil-2.2.0 psycogreen-1.0 psycopg2-2.5.4 pyPdf-1.13 pydot-1.0.2 pyparsing-2.0.1 pyserial-2.7 python-dateutil-1.5 python-ldap-2.4.19 python-openid-2.2.5 python-stdnum-1.2 pytz-2013.7 pyusb-1.0.0b2 qrcode-5.1 reportlab-3.1.44 requests-2.6.0 six-1.4.1 suds-jurko-0.6 vatnumber-1.2 vobject-0.6.6 xlwt-0.7.5
```

8) Run `odoo`

```
cd odoo  # change dir to the folder you cloned odoo to
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Re-check parameters, it looks like addons path you used is incorrect
./odoo.py --addons-path=addons --db-filter=mydb
```

Now you should see the output like this:

```
INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 9.0c
INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/Users/dev/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/9.0', u'/Users/dev/projects/odoo/addons', '/Users/dev/projects/odoo/openerp/addons']
INFO ? openerp: database: default@default:default
INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
```

9) Open `odoo` in your browser

- Go to http://localhost:8069
- The database setup window appears (see the first screenshot below)
- Enter databse name = `mydbodoo` (I think the prefix `mydb` is important here) and password `admin`
- You can also check the checkbox to load the demo data
- Click `Create database`
- Wait and you should be redirected to the `odoo` interface (see the second screenshot)

Done!

[image: Odoo databse setup]

[image: Odoo user interface]

### Update: Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 with virtualenv

Do the same as above, on step `(7)` do not run `pip install --user -r requirements.txt` and instead to this:

```
pip install virtualenv  # not sure here, sudo may be needed
mkdir ~/venv
cd ~/venv
mkdir odoo
virtualenv odoo
source ~/venv/odoo/bin/activate
cd ~/path/to/odoo
pip install -r requirements.txt  # no sudo here!
```

Now continue with step `(8)`. Each time, before starting odoo make sure to activate the virtualenv first:

```
source ~/venv/odoo/bin/activate
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

./odoo.py --addons-path=addons --db-filter=mydb
```

### Ubuntu 15.04

Prerequisites: I already had postgresql 9.4.5, nodejs 0.10.25 and python 2.7.8.

Installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git 
cd odoo
sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libevent-dev libxslt1-dev libxml2-dev 
pip install -r requirements.txt
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
./odoo.py --addons-path=addons --db-filter=mydb
```

That's all, now setup the same way as in the step (9) for Mac OS.

Comment: I did the same, updated question. The error looks like ``ImportError: No module named pyPdf``, still not working.

Comment: @devo then it means that pip install was not successful, `pypdf` is actually one of the requirements listed in the `requirements.txt`. Try to repeat the step number (7) and make sure there are not errors or if there are errors - then post them, it's not possible to say what went wrong just from the import error. My guess is that pip failed before the pypdf installation or during it.

Comment: I got success response as mentioned in question.And `sudo pip install pyPdf` says `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyPdf in /Users/anshad/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`

Comment: @devo Actually pip should be run without `sudo`, like `pip install --user pypdf==1.13`. Does it work if you run `python` from the command line and then do `import pyPdf`?

Comment: @devo try to re-run pip install without `sudo`, just `pip install --user -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Without the `sudo`, I am getting permission errors ``error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/anshad/Library/Python/2.7'``

Comment: @devo looks like something is not right with access permissions to the python's folders. The `--user` flag is supposed to install to the location accessible to your user, so `sudo` should not be needed. Another way to solve this - install [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), create a virtual environment for odoo and install all the python dependencies there (as well as then run odoo from this environment).

Comment: @devo I updated the answer, see the `Update: Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 with virtualenv`, it should help with dependenices.

Comment: Great! Something comes now. Got two menus but nothing else.When I clicked on preferences, it says `Error: Widget type 'html' is not implemented`

Comment: @devo is is complex to say just from the error text. Looking at code, it is something client-side related thrown from the javascript. Maybe some files are missing? Try to recheck if odoo repository was cloned completely and successfully or download an archived version. It should be easier this time since you already have all the dependenices and don't need to go through the whole installation process again.

Comment: Ok, I will try like that.

Answer (score 5):

Their might be a few issue of python modules, library, packages, or nodejs.

Try with below information:

1. Following command will install all python modules required by Odoo.

   ```
   pip install lxml
   ```
2. Check your *werkzeug* version. It will be *0.9.6,* if not than upgrade it.

   ```
   pip show werkzeug #this command will show the details of werkzeug
   pip install werkzeug==0.9.6 #this command will install werkzeug up to 0.9.6
   ```
3. Install *nodejs* via your preferred package manager ([homebrew](http://brew.sh/), [macports](https://www.macports.org/)) then install *less* and *less-plugin-clean-css*:

   ```
   npm install -g less
   npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
   ```

For more information, [Odoo9 setup documentation.](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html)

**NOTE**:

Default login and password will be *admin* and *admin*.

**EDIT: 1**

Try to resolve *ImportError: No module named pyPdf* with below command.

```
pip install pypdf
```

**EDIT: 2**

If you don't find relevance distributor than try with below command.

```
pip install --allow-unverified pyPdf pyPdf
```

Comment: I did all these, still not working. Updated question.

Comment: @devo, I have edited my answer which will resolve your *ImportError*

Comment: It says ``Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-pypdf (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-pypdf``

Comment: Says ``Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyPdf in /Users/anshad/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages``

Answer (score 1):

I did everything but couldn't run odoo on my mac 10.11.6.

I had this problem when I try to run odoo `./odoo.py`

`psycopg2 can't find symbol _PQbackendPID`

I found out I have many version of python installed ranging form 2.3 to 3.5

Deleted all version of python [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3819449/1378447)

```
$ brew uninstall --force python3
$ brew uninstall --force python
```

Clear all changes in `~/.bash_profile`

also deleted `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Then start from beginning:

```
 $ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

 $ brew update
 $ brew install python

 $ brew install postgresql
```

To start the PostgreSQL right now and automatically at system startup we run:

```
 $ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
 $ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
 // I had error: LaunchAgents not found 
 // If you have error you can download postgres from postgresapp.com to manually start the server
```

Install some dependencies

```
$ brew install freetype jpeg libpng libtiff webp xz
$ pip install --upgrade pip
$ pip uninstall virtualenv
$ pip install virtualenv
// Delete existing ~/odoo-env folder first
$ virtualenv ~/odoo-env  
$ . ~/odoo-env/bin/activate
```

Clone [git repository](https://github.com/odoo/odoo) branch 9.0

```
$ git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git -b 9.0
```

change to the cloned odoo directory (with `cd`) and run (you have to be in your virtual environment):

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If Successfully installed, run

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ python ./odoo.py
```

A wonderful tutorial by [Christoph Giesel](http://bloopark.de/en_US/blog/the-bloopark-times-english-2/post/setup-odoo-development-on-os-x-with-pycharm-109)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue and it seems that my system is not using the correct Six library.
What you can do first is to update your library

```
sudo pip2 install six -U
```

And once you have done that, your system can use the wrong library again. To check that, you can create a python file like this

```
#vi testsix.py to create the file
#type i to insert
import six
print six.__file__
#escape
#type wq to save
#chmod +x testsix.py
#python testsix.py
```

Then if you read

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc
```

Then you have to remove this file

```
rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.*
```

Then you can re-check the file testsix.py and check you get this path

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six.pyc
```

Then you should re-launch your odoo server.

I get this from the [Oriol Nieto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630114/matplotlib-issue-on-os-x-importerror-cannot-import-name-thread/31140136#31140136) I was trying to solve the previous Internal Server Error I get.

Note if you are using El Capitan and you meet some permission issue even with sudo, you may need to check this [link to remove some root access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled)