# Getting a python error when running the EB command

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip, ec2-api-tools

I installed ec2 api tools and when I run the command I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('awsebcli==3.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'eb')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 345, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2381, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2087, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebcore.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import ebglobals, base, io, hooks
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/hooks.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ..lib import aws
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 21, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 26, in <module>
    import botocore.credentials
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 22, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import parse
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 43, in <module>
    from . import tz
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tz import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ._common import tzname_in_python2, _tzinfo, _total_seconds
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/_common.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

I installed it using:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade awsebcli
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @EmettSpeer OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: You should give this question a read. They had the same problem as you are having with `six` on OSX 10.10. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630114/matplotlib-issue-on-os-x-importerror-cannot-import-name-thread

Comment: The second answer seems like it may work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib issue on OS X ("ImportError: cannot import name \_thread")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630114/matplotlib-issue-on-os-x-importerror-cannot-import-name-thread)