# Docker-compose ps error

Tags: docker-compose

I am new to docker-compose and getting the following error when I type in docker-compose ps.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 20, in        <module>
    from ..bundle import get_image_digests
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/compose/bundle.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .service import format_environment
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 37, in    <module>
    from .parallel import parallel_execute
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 10, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread as thread
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker-compose is written by python. It seems that you miss some python packages. You can refer to the following page of how to fix the python lib issue.
[Matplotlib issue on OS X ("ImportError: cannot import name _thread")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630114/matplotlib-issue-on-os-x-importerror-cannot-import-name-thread)

Alternatively, you can try to install docker-compose as a container, the docker container contains appropriate environment for docker-compose. 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-as-a-container