# Can't run `jupyter notebook` after fresh installation

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I did:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

And I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 61, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.multikernelmanager import MultiKernelManager
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .manager import KernelManager, run_kernel
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .session import Session
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 51, in <module>
    from dateutil.tz import tzutc
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tz import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ._common import tzname_in_python2, _tzinfo, _total_seconds
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/_common.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that some Matplotlib users had similar issue (see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630114/matplotlib-issue-on-os-x-importerror-cannot-import-name-thread)) and solved it by re-installing `dateutil`.

```
sudo pip uninstall python-dateutil
sudo pip install python-dateutil==2.2
```

You might want to try with a newer version (the latest is 2.6).

Comment: Holy sh**t that fixed it!

Comment: I get the same error when trying to uninstall python-dateutil