# Pandas import issues

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, import, anaconda

I have successfully installed Pandas through Anaconda in PyCharm. Unfortunately when I run Import Pandas this is what I get as the output:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 
"/Users/PycharmProjects/Security upload/Security 
upload.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Security upload/Security 
upload.py", line 3, in <module>
import pandas
File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-
packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from pandas.compat.numpy import *
File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-
packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 361, in <module>
from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-
packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 43, in <module>
from . import tz
File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-
packages/dateutil/tz/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .tz import *
File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-
packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 23, in <module>
from ._common import tzname_in_python2, _tzinfo, _total_seconds
File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-
packages/dateutil/tz/_common.py", line 2, in <module>
from six.moves import _thread
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

Could someone provide some insight on how to approach a solution?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I have Yosemite

Comment: What is the output of `pip list | grep -o 'six'`?

Comment: invalid syntax :-)

Comment: You might want to try `pip install six --upgrade` just in case.

Comment: I'm using my windows machine right now, so I'm trying to guess on the syntax. Try the upgrade command an see if that helps.

Comment: Thank, it is already up to date.

Comment: Take a look at the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630114/matplotlib-issue-on-os-x-importerror-cannot-import-name-thread). The users there said they had success on Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](https://github.com/opencobra/cobrapy/issues/490) and [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-shell/issues/161), you need to fix your dateutil package.

```
pip uninstall python-dateutil
pip install python-dateutil --upgrade
```

Maybe this:

```
sudo pip uninstall python-dateutil
sudo pip install python-dateutil==2.2
```

Comment: Thank for swift reply. I have already tried this, unfortunately I still have the sane issue.

Comment: You might need a specific version of dateutil. See my edit.

Comment: Thank, this I also tried didn't workout neither. I found workaround in Preferences of PyCharm within Project Interpreter selected anaconda/bin/python,instead of Python 2.7, the same for interpreter. Now it seems to work.

Comment: In any case could you explain why dateutil could help?

Comment: Okay, glad you were able to get it to work. I'm not entirely sure why it's needed though.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue and started installing jupyter and got few errors

reinstalling ipython worked for me

```
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed -U ipython
```

I also needed to reinstall pyzmq

```
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed -U pyzmq
```

after this I re-ran import pandas in ipython and it worked