# Pandas fails with dateutil/tz.py line 78 `self._name`, invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-dateutil, facebook-prophet

I have a pretty simple Prophet script that I'm running on a RHEL 6.6 Santiago system. When I run it, I get this traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "working_v1_runSplunkProphet.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/scadmin/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
  File "/home/scadmin/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable
  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.missing
  File "/home/scadmin/prophet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .conversion import OutOfBoundsTimedelta, localize_pydatetime
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.pyx", line 7, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dateutil/tz.py", line 78
    `self._name`,
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using python3.6 (3.6.8) and pip 21.0.1 from venv/lib/python3.6.site-packages/pip (python 3.6). I have also tried this outside the virtual env (same versions) and get the same traceback. I'm using pandas 1.1.15 and dateutil 2.8.1.

I've tried doing below as suggested from [Pandas import issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468073/pandas-import-issues).

```
pip uninstall python-dateutil
pip install python-dateutil --upgrade
```

I had this problem not too long ago and was able to fix it, but I can't remember what the fix was or seem to find the fix that worked last time.

Any help you can offer is much appreciated.

Comment: Similar thing happened to me, once. I had to manually go delete the package (in your case dateutil) from it's directory (in your case "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/") and then pip install it again. I would recommend you take a copy of the folder before deleting it, though. This can also reveal to you if you are mistakenly using the wrong pip or python.

Comment: This backtick syntax is specific to Python 2.x. You need to reinstall. When you use the `pip uninstall` and `pip uninstall` commands, make sure that you are using the `pip` that is associated with this specific Python installation. Since you are using a venv, this should be as simple as making sure the venv is active; but you can make sure by using `python -m pip` instead of `pip` (as long as `python` pulls up the right one, anyway).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have read many articles on pointing to the correct version, but I've done everything I've read/know to do. When I do `which python` in the venv it points to `~/venv/bin/python` and `python -V` gives `Python 3.6.8`, but I still get the same error with that python 2.x syntax. I also did what you and Ali_MM suggested. `python -m pip install python-dateutil` gives `Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in ./lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil) (1.15.0)` Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try creating a new venv and installing to it?

Comment: Yes, deleted it and started fresh twice